# how to sort an array function

Tags: python, pandas

i have this code

```
pd.unique(df_dataset["City"])
```

then this output comes out

```
array(['Marseile', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Lyon',
       'Seville', 'Palma', 'Munich', 'Hamburg', 'Madrid', 'Nice',
       'Granada'], dtype=object)
```

how do i add sort() function in the code

I have tried to run this

```
pd.unique(df_dataset["City"]).sorted("City", key=True)
```

but it doesn't seems correct

Comment: As I commented on @BENY's answer, sorting the whole column before taking the unique values is much less efficient than [sorting after](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68606929/16343464). Can you please test both on your data and give feedback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us just with `pandas`

```
df_dataset["City"].sort_values().unique()
```

Comment: It will be more expensive to sort first if there are many rows with duplicates, compared to a sort on unique values. You can test on something like `pd.Series(np.random.choice(list('ABC'), 1000000))` to see for yourself (factor 10 in this case).

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
sorted(df_dataset["City"].unique())
```

If you want to keep the numpy.array type:

```
import numpy as np
np.sort(df_dataset["City"].unique())
```